# UNION ALL FROM SELECT STATEMENT NOT WORKING

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have following 5 tables:

```
TABLE OLD_A ( CID, CNO, CNAME )
TABLE OLD_B ( DID, DNO, DNAME )
TABLE OLD_MAP ( CID, DID, TERRITORY )
TABLE NEW_A ( NCID, NCNO, NCNAME )
TABLE NEW_MAP ( NCNO, DNO, TERRITORY  )
```

I want to get `CNO` and `CNAME` from both new and old table so I made following query

```
DECLARE@TERRITORY varchar(16), @DNO varchar(16)

SELECT RESULT.`enter code here`CNO as CNO, RESULT.CNAME as CNAME, RESULT.Is_New_Or_Old as Is_New_Or_Old
FROM
(
  (SELECT C.CNO as CNO, C.CNAME as CNAME, 'OLD' AS Is_New_Or_Old [OLD_A] AS C LEFT JOIN [OLD_MAP] AS DCL ON C.ID = DCL.CID JOIN [OLD_B] AS D ON DCL.DID = D.ID WHERE C.TERRITORY = @TERRITORY AND D.DNO = @DNO )
  UNION ALL 
  (SELECT NC.NCNO as CNO, NC.CNAME as CNAME, 'NEW' AS Is_New_Or_Old  FROM [NEW_A] AS NC LEFT JOIN [NEW_MAP] AS CDTL ON NC.NCNO = CDTL.NCNO WHERE CDTL.DNO = @DNO AND CDTL.Territory_Id = @TERRITORY)
) RESULT 
ORDER BY CNO
```

But it is giving me error

```
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

AT LAST )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `FROM` after `'OLD' AS Is_New_Or_Old`

Those mistakes could be avoided by simple formatting

Comment: You coludn't see it, because you didn't format your query. I suggest you always do it